# Complex date manipulation

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I currently have to manipulate a varying amount of dates every day (anywhere from 200 to 1Mil plus), which I currently do with a rather long-winded AHK script that uses the COM interface to read the dates, and write back the new ones. My script is fine for the smaller amounts (anything up to 5,000) but due to the inherently slow nature of COM it takes a looong time to process the large quantities.

I've had some success in other tasks where using VBA or even a nested if-statement has provided me with much faster results, but my VBA knowledge is rather lacking.

**My Goal:**

To check a date that's currently in the format `dd/mm/yyyy ss/mm/hh`, for example `22/09/2015 45:12:23` and perform one of the following two tasks:

- If the input date is a Tuesday like in the example above to change the cell to just `22/09/2015` (cutting off the time section)
- If the input date is any other day of the week, it needs to be changed to the date of the following Tuesday (still cutting off the time section). For example, if the input date is `23/09/2015` or `25/09/2015`, it would need to be changed to `29/09/2015`.

I can make it loop through the column, but in VBA, that's about the extent of my skills.

**Answer**

Thanks to all of you for the speedy answers. I've managed to tweak one offered below to get something that suits my situation now. End result was (A1 being the input date):

```
=A1+(8-WEEKDAY(A1,12))*(WEEKDAY(A1,12)>1)-MOD(A1+(8-WEEKDAY(A1,12))*(WEEKDAY(A1,12)>1)-3,7)
```

Comment: Have a look at the VBA [Weekday function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Cheers, I can see how this can be helpful in determining how many days to add on etc. Any ideas about cutting off the Time part though? Adding days will just add 24 hours to the current variable and keep the time will it not?

Comment: The [TRUNC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRUNC-function-8B86A64C-3127-43DB-BA14-AA5CEB292721), [ROUND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C), [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDDOWN-function-2EC94C73-241F-4B01-8C6F-17E6D7968F53), [FLOOR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14BB497C-24F2-4E04-B327-B0B4DE5A8886) and/or [INT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-4D0598D4-FAC0-4ED3-BFBC-BE6DC8544183) worksheet functions come to mind.

Comment: For VBA, there's the `Int(...)` function. Stay away from the `CLng` conversion as this can round up to the next day after noon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do solve this by the Excel function `TEXT`, but unlike the VBA function `Format`, it can't return the number of the current weekday. So the best solution seems to be using VBA.

This function should solve your problem:

```
Public Function getTuesday(inputDate As Date)
If Format(inputDate, "w", vbTuesday) = 1 Then
    getTuesday = CDate(Int(inputDate))
Else
    getTuesday = CDate(Int(inputDate) + 8 - Format(inputDate, "w", vbTuesday))
End If
End Function
```

Comment: There is a worksheet [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940) as well as a VBA [Weekday function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: oh, yes. I didn't know that function. Then you can use `=WENN(WOCHENTAG(A1)=3;GANZZAHL(A1);GANZZAHL(A1+8-WOCHENTAG(A1;12)))` (that's the german version. For English Excel it should be something like this: `=IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=3,INT(A1),INT(A1+8-WEEKDAY(A1,12)))`. )

Comment: There are a number of possibilities. `=A1+(8-WEEKDAY(A1,12))*(WEEKDAY(A1,12)>1)` and `=A1+(7-MOD(B1-3, 7))*(MOD(B1, 7)<>3)` also work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch jeeped. That formula was close but if I inputted a Tuesday date with a time, It seemed to treat it as a wednesday and bump the date to the following tuesday... BUT by playing with it, I got the following which works great now :)                                                                         =A1+(8-WEEKDAY(A1,12))*(WEEKDAY(A1,12)>1)-MOD(A1+(8-WEEKDAY(A1,12))*(WEEKDAY(A1,12)>1)-3,7)

Comment: @JP-J If you want to use a worksheet formula, and the original is a "real date", then merely:  `=INT(A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1-3))` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if your date string is a string or a "real date" merely formatted in Excel to what you show.  The following VBA function should handle both instances.

The main part of the function is this line:

```
Tuesday = Dt + 7 - Weekday(Dt - 3)
```

where Dt is merely the relevant date, as a date only (no time).  This can also be used as a worksheet function.

---

```
Function Tuesday(ByVal Dt) As Date

'not sure if date is a string or a "real date"
'   so will test

Select Case VarType(Dt)
    Case vbString
        Dt = DateSerial(Mid(Dt, 7, 4), Mid(Dt, 4, 2), Left(Dt, 2))
    Case vbDate
        Dt = Int(Dt)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Date is unknown"
        Exit Function
End Select

Tuesday = Dt + 7 - Weekday(Dt - 3)

End Function
```

---